# Displaying both section header and custom view for table section header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table view with multiple sections. I want to display different section header titles and want to add a label on the right corner of each section at a right margin of 4px.

Can I implement both

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)iSection
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one of them will ever get called successfully. `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` will get precedence.

Define a view with a title label and another label that sits on the right corner and return it in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` with the values set.